# NuGet Entity Framework 6.1.3 as default not 7 Beta 4

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio-2013, nuget

Today I updated Visual Studio 2013 from Update1 to Update4 and the last version of NuGet. 
Now all time when I create a new solution, as default installs the Entity Framework 7 Beta 4 and I'm forced to change it in every new solution from NuGet Package Manager.

There is any way to put as default another version (for example the last stable, 6.1.3) for all future new solutions?

Thanks and sorry for my english.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The NuGet Package Manager in Visual Studio provides a ComboBox at the Top of the Dialog to switch between "Stable only" and "Include Prerelease". When I select "Stable only" I get `Entity Framework 6.1.3`. For "Include Prerelease" I get `Entity Framework 7.0.0-beta4`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Disable the "Include prerelease" option